# IOS adding and removing a subview memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, subview

I have tried for a few days now to figure this out but i feel that i have gone about it the wrong way or am just missing something very simple.

I have a single view which takes a swipe gesture, upon the swipe, it will try to create a subview from a nib file.  I am able to load the subview and remove the subview but there is a memory leak somewhere having to do with allocating the view or removing it.

In the current view .m file i am synthesizing my second view and in the .h file of the first view i also have a:
@class settingsviewcontroller

settingsviewcontroller *settingsview

and then 
@property nonatomic retain for the settingsview

In the code below i am allocating the subview.  It works without the [settingsview release[ but with that i get a bad memory error.

In the second part of the code, it is a function from the settingsviewcontroller to remove the view.  It takes an action from the user and animates the view offscreen, and attempts to remove it, or at least i think it tries too.

```
- (IBAction)swiping:(id)sender {
  //SettingsViewController *SettingsView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];

  settingsView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];

  CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
  [animation setDuration:0.5f];
  [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
  [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
  [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

  [self.view addSubview:[settingsView view]];
  [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];

  [settingsView release];
}



- (IBAction)rollOut:(id)sender {
  UIView *currentView = self.view;
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
  //[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(release)];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
  currentView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(currentView.frame.origin.x, 480);
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Please give me some direction in this, i can understand how to do it if you just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[self.view addSubview:[settingsView view]];

this code doesn't retain your settingsView,but "settingsview's view",so if you call [settingsView release]; the settingsView was released,if you call settingsView somewhere,you will got bad memory error.

this  "@property nonatomic retain for the settingsview", so you can replace [settingsView release]; by self.settingsView = nil;

Comment: I did what you suggested, setting the self.settingsView = nil.  After the view pops up, as soon as i click on anything, i get a crash and the bad memory again.  

The memory seems to be deallocated as the view is being displayed, and thus it does not actually exist when it is on screen.

Comment: [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];,You should setDelegate to self.view,like 
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self.view];

Comment: Thanks for that, i actually solved it just a minute ago by writing
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDone)];

and then having
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
in the animationDone function but i shall try it your way a bit later since it would be shorter